# OSError: The specified module could not be found. Error loading C:\intel_extension_for_pytorch\bin\intel-ext-pt-gpu.dll"

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, gpu, intel

I am using an Intel ARC A770 GPU.

I want to run my deep learning code on my local platform. I have installed `intel_extension_for_pytorch`. However, when I import the module, it gives me an error.

How can I activate my GPU for deep learning training?

Comment: `C\\:` is not a valid drive specifier.  It should be `C:`.  Where did that value come from?